# Stop scanning\contention on dual boot win7 win10 system

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, chkdsk, dualboot

I have a win 7 install, which I have added a drive and installed win 10 on a *separate drive*. To stop each windows install from messing with the other disk, I have disabled those disks in the device manager on each install. (In win 7 the windows 10 disk is disabled and vice versa).

I have a *shared disk* that can be seen by each install

There are two problems:

1. The shared disk (lets call it e:), every time I boot each installation wants to scan it. Can I disable `chkdsk` to stop it from checking the drive on boot? ( I still think it would be good to enable chkdsk on the booting drive)
2. Even if I press a key and get out of the `chkdsk` on boot, I can hear the drive being scanned by some process, what I think is happening is the security descriptors are being checked by some process and found to be different (I noticed this after I booted win7 after win10, while I was in win7 after about 10mins the drive activity stops)

Any clue as to what is going on with scanning after windows starts?

Is it the security descriptors or another process that is scanning the drive?

Comment: [Chkdsk-Problem in Windows 7 after parallel install of Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/chkdsk-problem-in-windows-7-after-parallel-install/c7bb1c5c-18f8-45da-8689-3d47952ca5d6) suggests switching off fast boot in Windows 10. And watching out for it being re-enabled after W10 updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to disable indexing, each time a different operating system is booted, the indexing system starts to re-index each drive.

Indexing can be disabled by going to the drive, selecting properties then disabling the "allow files on this drive to have contents indexed" to be unchecked (in the general tab).

The best way that I've found to stop one operating system from checking the others disk is to disable the disk's drivers in the device manager

Comment: How can a Windows install start indexing a disabled disk? Guess it's not really disabled, then. A disk that has not been dismounted because of Fast Boot will appear to be broken in any other Windows (or even Linux) installation. And all disk drives and NTFS filesystems will almost certainly be using the same generic drivers from Microsoft.

Comment: It's indexing the shared drives that are seen by both installs